# Angular JS Material and mobile design

Tags: css, angularjs, responsive-design, angular-material

I currently try to get my CV online. I thought with Angular JS and Angular Material it would be easy to get a mobile website.

My problem is (and I guess it is because both my mobile phone and my desktop have an Full HD screen) that I cannot use Pixel. The same problem is with cm, as 1 cm = 0,393701inch *96 ~38 px. I know I need something dpi indepentent.

My big problem is to get things DPI independent. If you re size the window to a mobile like smaller size everything seems to be good.

Desktop:
[image: Desktop 1]
[image: Desktop 2]
Mobile (Oneplus 2):
[image: Mobile]

The website can be found [here](http://reisi007.github.io/) and the repo is [here](https://github.com/reisi007/reisi007.github.io).
I am sorry for asking such questions, but I want the "mobile" view to be like the second picture. Currently the mobile view is very tiny and I do not know why.

Any hints appreciated. I really want to learn from this project.

Things like

```
<md-button ng-click="mainCtrl.toggleSidenav('left')"
  ng-show="$mdMedia('max-width: 400px')">
   Close
</md-button>
```

do not mind the devices DPI. But I do not know how to improve this...

Yours,

Florian

PS: Sorry that the pictures are so big....